# How can I convert a date in the format 2021-11-26T23:19:00.000+11:00 to 11/26/2021 23:19?

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I am trying to format the date into MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss format in my .ts script.
I tried using moment.

```
moment(dateToBeFormatted, "'YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm")
```

But when I do this, for  2021-11-26T23:19:00.000+11:00, I am getting 2026/11/01 20:19. I don't know what I am messing up here. If I give

```
moment(dateToBeFormatted).format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm")
```

I get Invalid date error.

Comment: I get `Invalid date` for the _first_ one, because that format doesn't match the string, and `'2021/11/26 12:19'` (which is what I'd expect) for the second. Also this doesn't seem to have anything to do with [tag:angular].

Answer (score 0):

Momentjs is using your local timezone instead of the one specified in the date.
If you need a specific timezone you should use moment timezone.
So in your case it would be:

```
 moment.tz(dateToBeFormatted, "America/Anchorage").format("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm")
```

https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/